# Is there a dependency or api that allows me to show specific places?

Tags: firebase, flutter, api, dependencies, maps

I’m trying to create a button that says show nearby hospitals, and for the user to click on this button and see the specific hospitals near him.. how can i do that? Is there a dependency or api that allows me to show specific places?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend Google Places API - On click of your button you can pass location to the API to search for specific types of businesses, return a map, a list, etc.

Check out the docs: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/overview